# Anyway to make this nested callback cleaner?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to make this set of AJAX calls cleaner. I've tried using `$.when()` ...but I could not really get it to work. I think it was due to not passing deferred objects...as my AJAX calls are inside of a model object.

This is what I have thus far (some code was excluded to simply):

```
var origin_form, destination_form; //assume string input from user
var destination, origin;

getOrigin();

//Gets origin data
function getOrigin(){

   //ASYNC CALL
   model.searchFeature(origin_form, 1, function(data){
     //additional callback code excluded
     origin = data; 
     getDestination();

   });
}

//Gets destination information
function getDestination(){

    //ASYNC CALL            
    model.searchFeature(destination_form, 1, function(data){
        //additional callback code excluded
        destination = data;     
        directions(origin, destination);
    });
}


 function directions(origin, destination){
    //Async call to request directions from google api
 }
```

Any advice would be great!

Edit: I'm looking for some solution similar to `$.when()`. Basically, I'd like to call `directions()`  after both `getOrigin()` and `getDestination()` are done without having the nested callbacks.

Comment: I assume in one of those functions you mean `origin = data` instead of `destination = data` *(probably the first one)*.

Comment: @user1689607 Yes, that is correct. I made the edit.

Comment: Make an AJAX call even cleaner: COMET and SOAP! *badumching* - Sorry, couldn't resist. :)

Comment: @deceze that's pretty hilarious. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a variable in the shared scope, just *pass* the values from function to function.

```
var origin_form, destination_form; //assume string input from user

getOrigin();

function getOrigin(){
   model.searchFeature(origin_form, 1, getDestination);
}

function getDestination(origin){           
    model.searchFeature(destination_form, 1, function(data) {
        directions(origin, data);
    });
}

function directions(origin, destination){
    //Async call to request directions from google api
}
```

---

Or using `Function.prototype.bind`, you can clean it up a bit more.

```
var origin_form, destination_form; //assume string input from user

getOrigin();

function getOrigin(){
   model.searchFeature(origin_form, 1, getDestination);
}

function getDestination(origin){  
    model.searchFeature(destination_form, 1, directions.bind(null, origin));
}

function directions(origin, destination){
    //Async call to request directions from google api
}
```

The first argument passed to `.bind()` is `null` because I don't know if you want the `this` value of `directions()` to be set. If you do, then replace `null` with whatever you want `this` to be.

Comment: I was kind of looking for something like `$.when().done()`. The origin and destination do not depend on one another, but `directions()` must be called after both are completed. Unfortunately, I can't seem to use `$.when()` with my `$.ajax` calls abstracted. Thanks for the suggestions though. They are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above by user1689607 gives a good suggestion on how to improve the 
callback arrangement.

I think you can further improve this code beyond just making the 
callbacks cleaner, however. For one, use camel case and jslint it, then:

```
// Use a closure/namespace for global abatement
MyNamespace = (function() {
  // Use a single 'var' declaration
  var originForm, 
      destinationForm, //assume string input from user
      destination, 
      origin;

  function init() {
    getOrigin();
  }

  //Gets origin data
  function getOrigin(){

     //ASYNC CALL
     model.searchFeature(origin_form, 1, function(data){
       //additional callback code excluded
       destination = data; 
       getDestination();

     });
  }

  //Gets destination information
  function getDestination(){
      //ASYNC CALL            
      model.searchFeature(destinationForm, 1, function(data){
          //additional callback code excluded
          destination = data;     
          directions(origin, destination);
      });
  }


  function directions(origin, destination){
    //Async call to request directions from google api
  }

  return {
    'init': init
  };
}());

MyNamespace.init();
```

Comment: Is there some optimization in using a single var declaration or is that just a convention? I always tend to group my variables by what they are used for as that is just my personal convention.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact performance implications, but you do definitely save some bytes.  I think the more important reason for doing this, is to provide a safety net for yourself.  If you declare vars all over your function scope, these are still hoisted to the top of the function definition, which can potentially introduce subtle bugs.

Comment: Also, thanks for the heads up on jslint. I didn't know that existed.